# Windows Library to play a video file

Tags: c#, windows, shared-libraries, media-player, media

```
this.Background = new System.Windows.Media.ImageBrush(new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(new Uri(label)));
```

The above code used the Media library to display an image from the Uri fed.(label contains the URL).

What library should I use to play a video file in the same manner.
(I need to play a video file instead of displaying and image)

Help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this.

It is located in System.Windows.Controls namespace and relies on the Windows Media Player. IF WMP is installed on your system MediaElement is an easy way to go.

The code to do this should look like this:

```
MediaElement me = new MediaElement();
// initialize and do other stuff to MediaElement
this.Background = new VisualBrush(me);
```

Comment: I cannot use the MediaElement, as I am displayng the control via a class.

Comment: CHEERS Wonko79 ..its not the frst time you are saving me ;) thnk u.